Server Permission Error while integrating Tablaeu to Amazon Athena
I've established an S3 bucket that has a Glue Table Scheme, and while trying to integrate it with Athena through Tableau, the Tableau Athena connector gives the following error:
Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source. Error Code: FAB9A2C5 Connection test failed: Could not get query execution ID: Service returned HTTP status code 404 (Service: Athena, Status Code: 404, Request ID: ). Unable to connect to the Amazon Athena server "athena.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
Thanks.

I've ensured that my AWS role has both S3 and Athena Full Access, and that my bucket is in the corresponding region (eu-north-1).
I've also downloaded the .jar driver and put it in ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers/.
I've checked that ports 443, 444 are open and available.


From the Tableau side of things which authentication method are you using to connect to Athena?   We have had success using it but shifting to use Redshift spectrum as the mechanism for Tableau to get to the data.
